# How can i diagnose a failed Install of Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, upgrade, optical-drive

I'm trying to upgrade from Leopard 10.5.8 to Snow Leopard, using the install CD.

The steps are:

1. Insert the DVD
2. Start the installation
3. When is about the 40-50% of the installation, the system restarts
4. Then ejects the DVD
5. Snow Leopard is not installed

How can I know what's going wrong? What I have to do to fix it?

Comment: Maybe she wanted to say that she doesn't like that DVD?
You can have a look into Log while installation is going. It's under Window menu I believe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has happened to me in the past. The solution that worked for me was making sure that the disc surface is clean and scratch free, and I mean very clean. Using normal CD wipes is good to get dirt off, but if it is scratched more than slightly, then you may have problems.

Or the disc may be defective from the factory, it does happen and they do exist.

Try talking to your local Apple Store about a possible replacement, or if worst comes to the worst, you can order one [here](http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MC573Z/A) (Apple still stocks them).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Solved going to Apple Store. The problem was the DVD device

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, it is worth pointing out that failed Snow Leopard installations can be recovered. This is useful knowledge if you have more than one copy of the media available (as a disc or a partition on a drive etc.).

Again, it'd be a good idea to head somewhere like an Apple store where they would likely help you finish off this install!